# Binding issue in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I tried to bind a NSTextView to a NSAttributedString declared in Document.swift for saving the text to a file but it doesn't do anything.

Here is the code in ViewController.swift :

```
var document: Document? {
    return view.window?.windowController?.document as? Document
}
```

And the Model Key Path:

```
self.document.text
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Bindings use Key-Value Observing (KVO) and all properties in the the key path must be [KVO compiant](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Bind to a KVO compliant keypath or don't use a binding.